# Pointer Protection and Performance

Tags: c++, pointers

I protect my pointers with `if` statements when developing to avoid crashing my application even if in theory the pointer should not be null.

My question is,
will removing these `if` checks after I am convinced that the pointer will indeed not be null under any circumstance improve the performance of my application by a non - trivial ammount?

Comment: Use `assert(mypointer)`. It depends **a lot** on where you do the checks but `if`statements can impact performance.

Comment: If your pointer cannot be null, use a reference instead.

Comment: You can use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` if you use modern C++

Comment: @Moia: While that is true and often good advice, both of them can store a null pointer so the same problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about performance but safety is still a concern you may consider adding the [__builtin_expect](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/builtinexpect.htm) (which most modern compilers support) flag to the if statements. This would preserve the safety precautions you have set up in your program but would tell the compiler to optimize the branch's jump labels for the condition where the pointer is not null.

However this still entails some slowdown because the branch conditions are still being computed. If the pointer is never *explicitly* declared as null it would be extremely advantageous to use a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) instead.